# Crontab en linux para backup

Tags: linux, crontab

realicé un sh en linux para sacar en una carpeta comprimida la copia de mi base de datos MySql. (He aquí el sh)

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -unombreusuario -pclave --opt nombrebd > nombrecarpeta/nombrebackup_$(date +%d%m%Y).sql
cd nombrecarpeta
tar -zcvf nombrebackup_$(date +%d%m%Y).tgz *.sql
rm nombrebackup_$(date +%d%m%Y).sql
```

Este sh me crea perfectamente la carpeta.
Ahora, tengo dificultad a la hora de realizar el cron que haga automaticamente la copia a una hora determinada del día ya que no encuentro el archivo, mi distribución de linux es centos y hasta ahora no se que mas a hacer.

Comment: ¿Usas MySQL o Postgres o MongoDB o Cordova? ¿Usas tar? ¿Con bzip2 o zip? ¿Usas bash o zsh? Vamos a poner tu pregunta en pausa, esperando a que agregues la información necesaria para poder ayudarte. Consulta esta guía: [http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Si no tienes interés en editar la pregunta, esto es lo que buscas: http://crunchify.me/1VIB66f

Comment: Nótese que estás realizando todos los cambios sin especificar la ruta del directorio donde se almacena. Dado que crontab corre en un entorno muy limitado, probablemente todo se esté almacenando en `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues no tienes más que crear tu propio archivo **crontab**. Para ello debes utilizar el comando:

> $ crontab -e

Con esto podrás editar el archivo crontab de tu usuario y se almacenará en /var/spool/cron/ para que el sistema lo actualice automáticamente.

A modo de recordatorio, el formato del archivo crontab es:

```
minuto hora dia mes dia-semana comando
*        *    *  *    *
```

Ejecutar tu script todos los días a las 10:30:

```
30 10 * * * usuario /home/usuario/scripts/tuscript.sh
```

Cuando quieras borrar el contenido de tu archivo crontab:

> $ crontab -r

Cuando quieras ver el contenido de tu archivo crontab:

> $ crontab -l

Espero haberte entendido bien ;-)

Comment: Al final ¿Te fue últil la respueta? Creo que tu problema era que no sabías crear el archivo contrab ¿no? Lo digo por si entendí mal ;-)

Comment: Si, fue de gran ayuda. Era exactamente lo que necesitaba.